# How do I split one excel into multiple excel files?

Tags: excel

I have a master excel -

```
ID1  ID2   A1  A2  B1  B2  C1  C2
...  ...   ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..
```

I need this to be split into

A.xlsx

```
ID1  ID2  A1  A2
...  ...  ..  ..
```

B.xlsx

```
ID1  ID2  B1  B2
...  ...  ..  ..
```

and so on. Is there a way to automate this rather than splitting it manually?

I recorded a macro and now I made it to split as individual worksheets. Is there a way to split these into separate files?

Comment: Have you tried recording a macro?

Comment: Added the macro in the description @KobyDouek

Comment: @Allan - record a macro of moving the sheet to a new book (right click on the sheet tab, select move or copy, choose new book) and then saving it. It works fine.